# edittext setvisibility giving null exception

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

I am trying to set my edittext to hide when i open the dialog box but when i check the checkbox it should get visible... this dialop is in my options selected menu
unfortunately i am getting this exception

> 07-31 15:23:31.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-31 15:23:31.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4143): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-31 15:23:31.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at com.EVS.homeautomation.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:1153)

here is the code

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.testing);
            dialog.setTitle("Configurations");

            final EditText up_num=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.unum));
            up_num.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           CheckBox cb= ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                {
                    if ( isChecked )
                    {
                        up_num.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // perform logic
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        up_num.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: Your up_num is null , try to  add 
up_num=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.unum));
When you setVisibility() .
in your case you should find the EditText every time you want to setVisibility .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invalidating EditText that is into the Dialog.So you have to initialize this EditText using this way:

```
EditText up_num=((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.unum));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you have to inflate the view then you can call `setContentView()`

So you can try :

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

LayoutInflater inflater1 = this.getLayoutInflater();

        final View customview = inflater1.inflate(
                R.layout.testing, null);
dialog.setContentView(customview);

            dialog.setTitle("Configurations");

            final EditText up_num=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.unum));
            up_num.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           CheckBox cb= ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                {
                    if ( isChecked )
                    {
                        up_num.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // perform logic
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        up_num.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });
```

i hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response brother.. :) but Md. Sajedul Karim's solution was more easier way around :)